# Assign control source dynamically from a different recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset, ms-access-2003

I have the following VBA code in my access.

```
Dim subform As Object
Dim formFilter As String

formFilter = "..."   'a SQL statement

Set subform = Me!my_subform.Form
subform.RecordSource = formFilter

subform.field1.ControlSource = "f1"
subform.field2.ControlSource = "f2"
subform.field3.ControlSource = "f3"

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 f4 FROM my_table " _
                           & "WHERE tableF1= '" & [f1] & "' AND tableF2 = '" & [f2] & "' " _
                           & "ORDER BY tableF5 DESC")
subform.field4.ControlSource = rs(0)
```

I have first bound my first 3 fields in subform to the fields of my record source. Then I need to bind the 4th field to a different recordset. This recordset has to refer to the first 2 fields of my subform.

However, I got a run-time error 2465. Access is not able to refer to the field [f1] and [f2] of my OpenRecordSet statement.

How should I fix this?

I use this form in a datasheet view. So I need to refer to not a single value of field1 and field2, but the entire columns of records have to be linked.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't bind a form to two different recordsets. You should be able to bind a form to a single recordset that accesses two different tables using a table JOIN in the SQL Statement. But be aware that recordsets which use JOINS in their SQL are generally Read-Only.

Comment: @HK1. Thanks. But I can't use JOIN because my field4 has more than 1 matching record. Using JOIN will give me duplicate field1, field2 and field3. That's why in my second recordset I need to select only the top 1 row.

Comment: Rather than add the solution in the question you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(from an earlier edit to the question, since rolled back:)*

Apparently the solution in this case was to use the following code in the `On Load` event handler for the ***subform*** instead of the ***main form***

```vbs
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 f4 FROM my_table " _
                           & "WHERE tableF1= '" & [f1] & "' AND tableF2 = '" & [f2] & "' " _
                           & "ORDER BY tableF5 DESC")
subform.field4.ControlSource = rs(0)
```

because the [f1] and [f2] controls were on the subform and therefore not visible from the Class Module code for the main form.